# iOS Google map api err:Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID:

Tags: ios, google-maps

Why my key is alway invalid?
My bundle identifier is the same as the BID in google gevelopers console,but ervrytimes I run my prj ,it print "Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID:".
How to fix that?

Comment: what is shows the error?

Comment: 2015-11-03 16:38:45.570 SDKDemos[2452:188692] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<CFData 0x79ee6270 [0xefc098]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}

Comment: 2015-11-03 16:38:45.570 SDKDemos[2452:188692] Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<CFData 0x79ee6270 [0xefc098]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-11-03 16:38:45.570 SDKDemos[2452:188692] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID:

Answer (score 2):

go to developer [console](https://console.developers.google.com). and enable **api key.** if you did it previously then regenerate you **api key** and give the **credential** again. **API key** and **server key** are different.

Comment: I am sure that I have enabled api key ,I've tried many times，but it still doesn't work, anyother idea？

Comment: which service you want to use?

Comment: road,distance,place,directon? which one?

Comment: ahh.I want to use road and mark some positions , but I can't show the map , I try to create a new iOS key,I  don't know why the bundle id is optional?